# How to keep the last row of a matching string in excel

Tags: excel

I want to remove all the rows except the last one for a matching userId "james.oconnor", i have a huge excel file and there are multiple rows of same "userId" with different "account" name. i want to keep only the last row having all the "account" name for a given userId - how can i do that?

How can i turn my Excel file from [image] to 
[image]

Many Thanks, Deepak

Comment: is that only one row of data needed from entire data in the sheet ? or need multiple rows of which is completely filled with?

Comment: What skill can you accept? Excel filter? VBA? Python Pandas?

Comment: What have you already tried?  If possible, please [edit] your question with a [mcve].  StackOverflow is for specific issues that you have with your code; it is not a free code-writing service.  You might want to check out the [tour] and [help]

Comment: @Regiz, Yes, for that userId thats the only row i need in the entire excel. However, i have many other such userid having multiple rows but i want the last row for each one of them.

Comment: Hi @Chronocidal, i have not tried any code as such, i tried lookup to look for last occurrence for a given userid `=LOOKUP(2,1/($A$2:$A$14=$P$2),$B$2:$M$14)` but did not work.

Comment: @deepakdimri Excel Formulae, such as that `Lookup` count as code!  However, `Lookup` doesn't work [quite how you seem to think](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/lookup-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a helper column that counts the number of accounts you have in that line, e.g. `=COUNTA(F2:AA:2)` in cell `E2` then sort the sheet by this new column in descending order (highest numbers on the top).

After that you can either go through `Remove Duplicates` (only filtering by the userId column) or a VLOOKUP to only keep the top ones.

Does that work for you?

Comment: @deepakdimri I'm very glad to hear that, you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Counter  As Long, i As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim LookUpValue As String

    LookUpValue = "james.oconnor"

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Counter = 0

        For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1

            If .Range("A" & i).Value = LookUpValue Then

                Counter = Counter + 1

                If Counter > 1 Then
                    .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
                End If

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: if the answer helps you vote it to helps others with the same issue.